# Break multiple for loops in java when a condition is met Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've four `String[]` which contain some words and have different length. These keywords get searched inside a txt  file and if even one word is found the loop will break. The problem is how can I stop other loops if the word is found in first array ? Like If the word if found in 1st array I want the other for loops to be break else if the word isn't found then I want the 2nd loop to iterate. I tried it in nested for loop but I didn't worked for me as I've not used nested for loop.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class practice {

static String wfound;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String a[] = { "universe", "world", "html" ,"name"};
    String b[] = { "animal", "Bird", "HTML" };
    String c[] = { "choclate", "HTML", "hello" };
    String d[] = { "css", "side"};

    String file= new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D://test1.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    for (String an : a) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + an + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(file);
        if (m.find()) {
            wfound = an;
            System.out.println("In array 1: " + an);
            break;
        }
    }
    for (String ab : b) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + ab + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(file);
        if (m.find()) {
            wfound = ab;
            System.out.println("In array 2: " + ab);
            break;
        }
    }
    for (String ac : c) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + ac + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(file);
        if (m.find()) {
            wfound = ac;
            System.out.println("In array 3: " + ac);
            break;
        }
    }
    for (String ad : d) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + ad + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(file);
        if (m.find()) {
            wfound = ad;
            System.out.println("In array 4: " + ad);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: There are a few options, but the most OOP way I see would be a chain of responsibility pattern. At a minimum, split this up into separate methods. And maybe try a `String[][]`.

Comment: You can create a boolean and set it to false and if your string is matched, set it true and check it every time before you enter a new loop.

Comment: @SaatvikRamani So I've to wrap these loops into while loop ?

Comment: Just use a 2d-array.

Comment: @john - no.   Just rewrite `for (...)`  as `if (!flag) for(...)`, for all loops except he first.

Comment: No, I meant like an if condition before every loop but that doesn't sound very idiomatic. My best bet would be having a 2-d array of your string arrays with a nested loop.

Comment: But given the code as presented, I'd just replace each `break` with `return`, since it appears that once the method has found a match, it's not required to do anything else at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's too much code repetition for my taste.  I'd start by factoring out the common processing:

```
String findAndPrint(String[] arr, String file, int n) {
    for (String an : arr) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+an+"\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(file);
        if (m.find()) {;
            System.out.printf("In array %d: %s%n", n, an);
            return an;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then, in main, you can write:

```
if (findAndPrint(a, file, 1) != null)
   return;
if (findAndPrint(b, file, 2) != null)
   return;
if (findAndPrint(c, file, 3) != null)
   return;
if (findAndPrint(d, file, 4) != null)
   return;
```

or even

```
String[][] s = { a, b, c, d };
for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++){
   String wfound = findAndPrint(s[i], file, i);
   if (wfound != null) {
       // TODO: process string 'wfound' here
       return;
   }
}
```

In this second rewrite, the separate method is not "needed" but in my opinion it still contributes to clarity.

If the example code requires more work after finding a match, you can (I am sure) change this accordingly.

The key point is: don't repeat code.

Comment: Is there any way I could access the wfound variable which stores the word, inside my main function. I declared it as static in class but still I can't access it

Comment: change the return type of 'findAndPrint'  to return the string if found, and null if not found.

Comment: I replaced return true to the variable and false to null but still I can't access variable

Comment: I was hoping you'd figure it out yourself, but ok. Done.  For what it's worth, you don't want to 'access a variable' (which in this case was local to the subroutine) but to use the return value. (which you can store in some variable in the calling routine, as I did here).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `return` instead `break`:

```
   public class practice {

    static String wfound;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String a[] = { "universe", "world", "html" ,"name"};
        String b[] = { "animal", "Bird", "HTML" };
        String c[] = { "choclate", "HTML", "hello" };
        String d[] = { "css", "side"};

        String file= new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D://test1.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        for (String an : a) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + an + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(file);
            if (m.find()) {
                wfound = an;
                System.out.println("In array 1: " + an);
                return;
            }
        }
        for (String ab : b) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + ab + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(file);
            if (m.find()) {
                wfound = ab;
                System.out.println("In array 2: " + ab);
                return;
            }
        }
        for (String ac : c) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + ac + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(file);
            if (m.find()) {
                wfound = ac;
                System.out.println("In array 3: " + ac);
                return;
            }
        }
        for (String ad : d) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + ad + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(file);
            if (m.find()) {
                wfound = ad;
                System.out.println("In array 4: " + ad);
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is overly complicated.  There's no reason for the `if (isFound)` check to be **inside** the subsequent loops.  And if all you're going to do when the flag is set is to return, you might as well omit the flag, and return at the point you find a match.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was editing my answer when you wrote the comment. Thx)

Comment: @DmitriiBykov Is there any way I could access the wfound variable which stores the word, inside my main function. I declared it as static in class but still I can't access it

Comment: In this case, you can't access it because the program is finished when you find a match -- because it returns out of 'main'.  But that is exactly the effect implied by your original posting; if you skip the subsequent loops, then nothing more is done before the end of the program.